# Hide scrollbar on image when scrolling down

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

I was following this example: 
`http://jsfiddle.net/qqPcb/`

I was trying to get it to work with an image, but the scrollbar is still showing. What am  doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/H27BK/122/

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/rJmDwjF.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>

#parent {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#child {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: you missed the part where the child has to have a larger width so the scrollbar is hidden outside the parent bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child must be larger than de scrollbar, try this:

```
#parent {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#child {
    width: 520px;
    height: 320px;
    overflow: auto;

}
```